# return value javascript UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone

i'm trying to get the return value of a javascript function(for example: `return "hello"`) with iPhone SDK.

On OS X the WebView method `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` returns a NSString containing the js function return value, but on the iPhone no value is returned.

How can I solve this?

---

I found a private UIWebViewDelegate method

```
- (void)webView:(id)fp8 runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(id)fp12 initiatedByFrame:(id)fp16
```

invoked when the alert() function is used in the js script. So I can get the "return" value just by calling `alert(myReturValue)`.

That doesn't solve my problem, because I need something in the public SDK.

Answer (score 29):

The return string is the result of the last Javascript statement. Do **not** put `return` in front of it!

The minimum code that worked for me:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"function f(){ return \"hello\"; } f();"];
NSLog(@"result: '%@'", result); // 'hello'
[webView release];
```

So I had to add the `UIWebView*` to a view (otherwise it would crash afterwards), but didn't have to load anything into the webview.

Notice that the last statement is just "`f();`", so the returned string will contain the result of the evaluation of `f()`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I tried call some functions from google maps API.

There was a problem with returning objects, so I solved it by function toString().

```
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                @"map.getBounds().toString();"];
```

Comment: can you answer this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793698/how-to-make-image-maps-clickable-using-uiwebview-in-iphone